# How to add new elements to ListModel in QML directly from Python

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm new to Python/QML and I can't seem to figure out how to add new ListElements to the ListModel directly from Python. here is the code:

Python file:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine('tutorial.qml')
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Window Title")
     ListModel {
        id: listmodelid
        objectName: "listmodelobject"
            ListElement { 
                name: "Oliver A" 
                student:false
                credits:2
            }
            ListElement { 
                name: "Rick Liam" 
                student:true
                credits:4
            }
    }

    ListView {
        model: listmodelid
        height: 200
        delegate: ItemDelegate{
            text: name
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to add new elements from a list that looks like this in python;

```
some_list=[{"name":"John Doe","credits":3,"student":True},{"name":"John Deer","credits":7,"student":True},{"name":"John Cena","credits":0,"student":False}]
```

I've tried getting the ListModel Object and using `.setProperty('model',some_list)` but didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The method `setProperty` of `ListModel` takes three arguments: `setProperty(index, property, value)` and sets the value of the property of one entry of your `ListModel`. You might be looking for `append(...)`. However, rather than filling a QML ListModel, you should create a `QAbstractListModel`-descendent in Python and expose that to QML.

Comment: @derM Could you please provide some code if you have time? Would greatly appreciate  :)